# Does the TYPO3 TypoScript condition backend.user.isLoggedIn harm caching?

Tags: caching, typo3, content-management-system, typoscript, typo3-12.x

Hello TYPO3 community

**I want to add functionality to the frontend only when a user is also logged into the TYPO3 backend at the same time.**

I already tried the `<f:be.security.ifAuthenticated>` ViewHelper, but it seems not to work with enabled caching in the frontend on production, since it will get cached and visible to all users.

Since TypoScript is only relevant for the frontend only, I assume that the available condition `[backend.user.isLoggedIn]` should work properly. **My only concern is, if this will harm the caching or page speed on the production system?** I found nothing about that, but maybe you can provide further information?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will have a lack of performance, when a logged in backend user is needed to display the frontend.

But the performance problem is not belonging to the use of the condition `[backend.user.isLoggedIn]`. But rather from the fact that when your are logged in to the backend, the http request header `Cache-Control`and `Pragma` is set to `no-cache`.

Maybe you can disable this behavior. Not sure if this is possible.

**Be aware of:**

Some hosting providers implements caching, that is executed before TYPO3 is executed. So you should check if this is the case for your production site, before implementing mechanisms like `[backend.user.isLoggedIn]`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! It is not a problem if the logged-in backend user has a lack of performance for me. 

My fear is that this will also harm the performance of normal non-backend logged-in users?